# ascii and binary - displays as it should but read returns garbage

Tags: c++, file-io

This in main :

```
std::ofstream rainbow_file("rainbow.bin", std::ios::binary);
rainbow_file.write((const char*) p.pass, password::PASSWORD_SIZE);
rainbow_file.write((const char*) h.hash_, hash::HASH_SIZE);
```

where :

```
class hash
{
public:
    static const size_t HASH_SIZE = 32;
    uint8_t hash_[HASH_SIZE];
...
}
// similar for pass
```

I open the rainbow.bin file in Notepad++ and I see my passes as passes (characters A-Z, @, !, a-z, 0-9) and the binary garbage of the hashes. When later I do :

```
std::ifstream rainbow_file("rainbow.bin", std::ios::binary);
rainbow_file.read((char*) p.pass, password::PASSWORD_SIZE);
rainbow_file.read((char*) h.hash_, hash::HASH_SIZE);
```

I get the passes back as binary garbage. I tried many things (like opening two streams - one not in binary mode - and using seekg to move the file pointer separately, trying various casts etc) but for the life of me I can't get this to work. And I am  very curious why. And frustrated. I repeat in npp I see all things in order.

Edit : these are different control flows and the stream is closed() properly

**Edit2** : works ! Still see answer below and comments for a more C++ way of doing it

Comment: Can I see the code that fills in hash_?

Comment: `blake256_hash( uint8_t *out, const uint8_t *in, uint64_t inlen )` from http://131002.net/blake/

Answer (score 1):

```
std::ifstream rainbow_file("rainbow.bin", std::ios::binary);  /* OK */

rainbow_file.read((char*) p.pass, password::PASSWORD_SIZE);   /* KO */
rainbow_file.read((char*) h.hash_, hash::HASH_SIZE);
```

should be replaced by:

```
rainbow_file.read ( reinterpret_cast < char*> (&(p.pass)), password::PASSWORD_SIZE * sizeof(uint_8t));
rainbow_file.read ( reinterpret_cast < char*> (&(h.hash_)), hash::HASH_SIZE * sizeof(uint_8t));
```

This way you do not assume sizeof ( uint_8t ) == sizeof (char).

In C++ h.hash_ is an array of type uint_8t(&)[hash::HASH_SIZE], not a pointer... You could have easily caught the problem by letting your compiler checking the cast but unfortunately, you've used C style cast, which are not checked.

NEVER USE C STYLE CASTING METHOD IN A C++ PROGRAM !!!

But in fact you could have it done like that in pure C++, error free:

```
std::ifstream rainbow_file("rainbow.bin", std::ios::binary);

rainbow_file >> p.pass >> h.hash_;
```

Comment: "This way you do not assume sizeof ( uint_8t ) == sizeof (char)." You're still making that assumption. `reinterpret_cast` is not type-safe. The standard does not require that it make any kind of sense; it can provoke implementation-defined behavior. Indeed, the only difference between `reinterpret_cast` and C-style casts in this case (besides the fact that you cannot accidentally cast away a `const`) is that one of them is *longer* to type.

Comment: Thanks - +1 for the try - but : `rainbow_file >> p.pass >> h.hash_;` reads the pass correctly - the pass is 6 bytes - and then starts reading into h.hash_ at the 20th byte - not the 7th (??WHY????) and  will crash on line `rainbow_table_.rainbow->push_back(std::make_pair(p, h));`. Trying to follow your `reinterpret_cast < char*> (&(p.pass))` I start to see the problem : nothing is read into the arrays. The pointer is not passed correctly neither by you nor me

Comment: It reads from the twentieth byte cause byte 19 is a space, duh - so apparently the crash is due to an overflow in pass and/or hash_ lol

Answer (score 1):

If non ascii char ( seems it is a binary file ) is used in your file, you have to use std::noskipws stream manipulator. You can also explicitly specify the width of each field to be loaded in addition thus the resulting code `rainbow_file >> std::noskipws >> std::setw ( password::PASSWORD_SIZE ) >> p.pass >> std::noskipws >> std::setw ( hash::HASH_SIZE ) >> h.hash_;`.

@Nicol Bolas I did not assume anything about type size of uint_8t but the pointer's size ! Casting pointer is inherently unsafe, what do we know about the real in-memory layout of a type ? Nothing. This is the only reason why it is unsafe to cast non derived type's pointers. I used reinterpret_cast in order to inform other developpers as well as the compiler that I know what I'm doing, reinterpret cast works the same as static cast in everyday use. As I can see everyone saw the trick, so I did a good job !

Finaly I have to repeat that `p.pas`s and `h.hash_` ARE NOT POINTERS in C++ !!!!!! It is POD, the C-style cast cannot inform you, the C++-style does ...

Comment: Well - I 'll accept this if it works :) - but why did it work on `rainbow_file.write((const char*) p.pass, password::PASSWORD_SIZE);
` ? Can you elaborate - comment with a link - on the p.pass _not_ being an array pointer ? - what surely worked was `char temp_h[32]; rainbow_file.read(temp_h, 32); memcpy(h.hash_, temp_h, 32);` but I wanted something more elegant and efficient - the `std::setw` omission in the previous answer is pure C++ strcpy() BO btw :D

Comment: Actually my original worked - don't know why it didn't initially (the code is more complicated than posted) - so `rainbow_file.read((char*) p.pass, password::PASSWORD_SIZE);
` works ! But yours is clearly a more C++ way of doing it - doesn't work though - on first pass it writes 5 chars +'\0' into p.pass and 16 chars +'\0' into h.hash_ - then one '\0' into p.pass[0] and nothing to h.hash_ and goes like this (it's in a huge loop) till the end. What could be wrong ?